# Maven multi-module dependency resolution

Tags: java, maven

When using Maven with a multi-module project like:

```
/pom.xml
/project-a/pom.xml
/project-b/pom.xml
```

If the root POM builds both modules A and B, and B **depends on** A, when I'm running a `mvn package` and I run the build from the **root POM**:

Q: Does the build for B pull from the current build "reactor" to locate the dependency for A? (ie. the changes in A that are *being built*) Or does it **always** go to the local repository?

Basically I'm trying to figure out if I need to be running `mvn install` when there are changes in A that B depends on, or whether I can just run `mvn package` to save some time.

Comment: If you run it from the root via `mvn clean package` or maybe `mvn clean verify` the dependencies will be resolved within the reactor. This means in consequence that you never need to do `mvn clean install`. If you ever face the situation that you need to do `mvn clean install` on a multi module build that means that your dependencies within the modules are not correct. And no it will not go to the remote repository for modules which are contained in the reactor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run it from the root via `mvn clean package` or maybe `mvn clean verify` (If you have integration tests) the dependencies will be resolved within the reactor.

This means in consequence that you never need to do `mvn clean install`. If you ever face the situation that you need to do `mvn clean install` on a multi module build that means that your dependencies within the modules are not correct.

And no it will not go to the remote repository for modules which are contained in the reactor.

Comment: Thank you! It was very hard to find any reference to this behavior in the Maven docs.

Comment: @CraigOtis Can you make a suggestion where to put such information or at best would be to open an issue on https://github.com/apache/maven-site/issues ? and fabulous would be to create pull request for the documentation on the page you think it belongs...

Comment: Perhaps on the multi-module page? https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html That's where I remember looking.